# A different way to access a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, stack-overflow

Here is my code, am looking for a different way to access a dictionary, which is an alternative to this one because of a stackoverflow. It was not possible to find the errors inspite of debuging and setting up the break points. When I used a dictionary of
       **Dim education As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))**

it worked very well, but this one is giving me problems. What's your advise?

```
        checkWord = replacements.Keys.ElementAt(nextCheckIndex)

        foundIndex = RichTextBox1.Find(checkWord, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
        If foundIndex > -1 Then
            ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear()
            For Each replacement In replacements(checkWord)
```

Comment: What errors are you talking about? What are your problems? I am not a mind reader and I don't have a crystall ball to look at your screen. Please  you should explain your errors with precision, Nothing in the code above seems wrong.

Comment: @steve. I get a stackoverflow here: **foundIndex = RichTextBox1.Find(checkWord, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)**

Comment: What is the value of _checkWord_ ? Are you sure that this word is present in the richtextbox text?  There is no reason to get a StackOverflow exception with Find. Try to use the debugger and check what are the values of your variables before reaching the exception. By the way are you sure that the exception is a StackOverflowException and not an IndexOutOfRangeException coming from the previous line (ElementAt.....)

Comment: @steve. It is not index out of range. IndexOutofRange comes when searching an index that is greater than the list size. The value of checkWord, is the word match against the dictionary. **Dim checkWord As String= replacements.Keys.ElementAt(nextCheckIndex)**

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CheckForReplacementText()

    Dim foundIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim start As Integer = 0

    Try
        For Each checkWord In replacements.Keys

          foundIndex = RichTextBox1.Find(checkWord, start, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
          If foundIndex > -1 Then
              ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear()
              For Each replacement In replacements(checkWord)

                  ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(replacement, Nothing, Sub(sndr As Object, ea As EventArgs)
                                                                    RichTextBox1.SelectedText = GetWordWithOutBracketedText(kamau)
                                                                End Sub)

                  ContextMenuStrip1.Show(RichTextBox1, RichTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart + RichTextBox1.SelectionLength))
              Next
          End If
        Next

    Catch e As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The Extra Next should not be there, but for the correction. Thanks. But it is not showing the context menu when you removed this part here: `Else
                nextCheckIndex = nextCheckIndex + 1
                CheckForReplacementText()
            End If`  Can you help me with this? It is as if that part is very vital to run the program.